# Are there any Linux libraries/package that allow to profile a java application with using profiling tools like visualvm etc?

Tags: java, profiling

I have to find the time spent in a method or the current method being executed in java program with out connecting to profiling tools like visualvm or jconsole.

Are there any such libraries in Linux that provide in-built profiling of a java application.

Comment: Probably only written in Java. Find out what visualvm or jconsole does, and copy that. It will connect to the JVM and do some profiling stuff.

Comment: visualvm is probably open-source